# Get a return value from a screen'd command

Tags: gnu-screen

I'm running a process in a screen (on Ubuntu 13.10, if it matters). I can execute a command within that screen with:
screen -p 0 -X eval 'stuff \"$command\"\015'

I'm not 100% sure what this command is doing to begin with, though it's functioning correctly. The reason behind it is I'm running a Minecraft server (still) and this screens in to the correct screen, and throws the command on the running command line. So that's good, so far.

But what I'd like is to be able to run this command with a return value. So for example, if I were to run a "list" command, it'd tell me how many people and who is online, but I need to capture that output and put it somewhere.

Anyone know of a way to accomplish this? I can't tell the minecraft server command line to redirect the output somewhere else since it doesn't have direct command line access, so the only way I could do this would be to grab all output of the screen while I'm connected ... but I'm not sure if that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be able to view the logs? can you not view a running log of the server ?

Comment: Not exactly (unless I misunderstand). I want to run this in the background (or I'd just leave the command line up) but still be able to hook in and send / receive information from the command line. In that I suppose I could write a custom wrapper that also listened on a port for custom commands to pass in and responded with their output, yes, this could be some kind of an answer. Though ... that's /way/ more effort than I am going to spend on this. Was hoping there was a way to just get the stdout from screen since there's obviously a way to attach and send stdin.

Comment: changed answer my apologies i thought you was looking for a way to do it yourself, i am fully aware that this would take a long time so i see why you wouldnt.

Comment: That's a possibility. I could issue the command, then wait a moment, grab the latest logs and parse them for the output I expect ... then grab again if the output isn't there (waiting on the logs to actually write, plus possible buffering, I assume). That'd work (and be much simpler to implement than a wrapper ;) ), but I'm going to leave the question open in case someone knows a way to actually capture the reply directly. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Very we'll sir, glad I could be of some assistance at least :,)